# How to maintain checkbox disabled state when returning to page using Back?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, back

I'm having difficulty maintaining the disabled state of a check box when going back in the browser.

I've create these two sample pages to demonstrate my issue.

What do I need to do in order to ensure the checkbox remains disabled when returning to the previous page?

```
test1.html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="test" action="/">
        System <input type="checkbox" id="chkSystem148" onclick="this.disabled = true;"/>
        <a href="test2.html">Go to test2</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


test2.html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.back(-1); return false;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add a JavaScript function that sets a cookie and checks it onLoad.

Answer (score 0):

As mblase75 commented, use cookies. or other form of persistent storage, like localstorage. a hash might also work, don't remember on the spot if that adds to the history or if only in newer browsers that allow to push items to the history.

Comment: Thanks Martin. What I find confusing though is that it remembers whether the checkbox is checked or not, but it doesn't remember whether it is disabled or not.